# creating charts in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'd like to create a chart that breaks down my yearly transactions on a monthly basis and gives me the total sale per month.
I have a table with every transaction and its date. 
I'd like to use jquery to do this. 
What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Flot, which is a JS plotting library for jQuery. http://code.google.com/p/flot/ Examples: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems here:

1. generating the data for the chart
   from the data you have and
2. selecting the chart tool itself.

It looks like you want data for a line chart or a column chart where x-values are months and y-values are aggregates of sales per month.

If the transaction data currently is printed to a *HTML table*, you'll need to scrape it and aggregate the monthly sales values in javascript to an array, `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`,  and pass this new array to the jQuery chart plugin of your choice.

If the transaction data is in a *database table*, you should use SQL for aggregation and make the resultset accessible to the chart plugin. Easiest way to do this is to print the results server-side to a javascript variable value, using an inline expressions like:

```
var data = <%= SalesPerMonth() %>;
```

where SalesPerMonth() is a string-valued server-side function returning `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`

On the jQuery chart plugins, I recently [evaluated](http://www.flowmarks.com/2009/09/embedded-reporting-with-chart-controls.html) a bunch of chart controls, and really liked [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for time-series charts. Another option is [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/), it has nice looking charts with [data point highlighting](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/highlighterTests.php) too. But in the end I didn't choose a jQuery plugin but [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/), which is a Flash charting component.

If any javascript charting tool goes, not just jQuery plugins, you should check [Emprise Javascript Charts](http://www.ejschart.com/index.php) and read the Steve Reynold's other article, [5 Javascript Chart Alternatives](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/javascript-chart-alternatives/).